# Is こんこん onomatopoeia for foxes?

Tags: onomatopoeia, animals

I mentioned [こんこん](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-onomatopoeia/) to a native speaker, and he hadn't heard it before.

Is こんこん the standard onomatopoeia for foxes? If not, what does the fox say?

Comment: I'm not at all sure if it is intentional, but the way the characters are strung together looks like a fox.

Comment: At least 万葉集 tells us fox cry's is "kon".　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1012827495

Answer (score 19):

「こんこん」 is just about the only onomatopoeia for a fox's cry.  It is difficult to believe what your native speaker friend(?) has told you.  I honestly do not even know of an alternative onomatopoeia for that.

In fact, 「こんこん」 can even mean a "fox" itself just like 「わんわん」 can mean a "dog" when speaking to toddlers.

See what [デジタル大辞泉{だいじせん}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%93%E3%82%93-506073#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) says.

> ［副］

> １ せきをするときの声を表す語。

> ２ **狐{きつね}の鳴{な}き声{ごえ}を表{あらわ}す語{ご}。**

> ３ 固い物が軽く打ち当たったときに発する音を表す語。「扉をこんこん（と）ノックする」

> ４ 雪や雨などがさかんに降るさま。

> ［名］**狐のこと**。

My own TL of the above:

> [Adverb]:

> 1. Onomatopoeia for coughing

> 2. Onomatopoeia for a fox's cry

> 3. Knocking sound

> 4. Onomatopoeia for heavy snow or rain

> [Noun]: A fox.

Here is a famous children's song about foxes which is named none other than 「こぎつねこんこん」 and I still could not believe there is a native speaker who grew up not listening to or singing it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOuoIQWlrHs

In children's stories as well, I could not remember another onomatopoeia used for a fox.

Comment: 今の若者は「♪ こぎつねこんこん、やまのなか～」とかいう歌、もう知らないのよ、きっと・・https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSMLzcj50Ps

Comment: あ、そうなん？平成生まれのボクでもその歌知ってるのに・・

Comment: こっちの歌のほうがうまかったやん～　https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeaVwGBEVBU　←ここに「ドイツ民謡」って書いてある！知らんかった

Comment: 同じく平成生まれですがわかります

Comment: その歌、今の子供でも知っとるよ。この前家帰りに狐があらわれて、「きゃーー」ってないたら、息子がえ？コンコンじゃないと？ってびっくりしとったと　（笑）