# What is the relationship between "Fuchs du hast die Gans gestohlen" and 「こぎつねこんこん」?

Tags: song-lyrics, music

There is a [German children's song](https://youtu.be/oz--4Jmnr1w?t=20) named "Fuchs du hast die Gans gestohlen" about a fox stealing a goose. According to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs,_du_hast_die_Gans_gestohlen) the melody comes from another song named "Wer eine Gans gestohlen hat" which is about geese but not about foxes.

There is a [Japanese children's song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOuoIQWlrHs) named 「こぎつねこんこん」 (judging by the YouTube title) with a very similar melody that is also about foxes. I found a [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F%E3%81%8E%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AD) that may or may not be about the song. (I don't speak Japanese.)

What is the relationship between the two versions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the Japanese language.

Comment: Andre du hast die Antwort gelesen http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43266/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The German *Fuchs, Du hast die Gans gestohlen* is the original song. (The modern version is due to Ernst Anschütz (1824).)

The Japanese 『小ぎつね』 (or 小ぎつねこんこん) is a version by 勝【かつ】 承夫【よしお】 *Yoshio Katsu*, first listed in the textbook 『三年生の音楽』 "Music for the third grade" published in 1947 by the Ministry of Education, Science and Culture.

The song is still contained in the [ministry-approved textbooks](http://www.kyogei.co.jp/publication/textbook/h27_elementary_school/a2.html) (now for second grade), listed as:

> 曲名： 小ぎつね、 作詞者： 勝 承夫 （日本語詞）、 作曲者： ドイツ民謡

which translates to

> *Title:* 小ぎつね, *Lyrics:* Yoshio Katsu (Japanese lyrics), *Music:* German folk song